# Using pattern matching in R, how can I find if there are more than one matches per character string?

Tags: r

I have the following vector:

```
vector1 <- c("Frank frank", "Frank", "Fred", "frank")
```

I wish to determine how many times the word `'Frank'` or `'frank'` appear in the vector. I want to count individual occurrences and keep track of how many times this pattern appears in each character string within the vector.

The result should look like this:

```
2 1 0 1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_count`, wrap the pattern in modifiers e.g. `regex` and make use of the additional arguments i.e. `ignore_case` which is by default `FALSE`

```
library(stringr)
str_count(vector1, regex('Frank', ignore_case = TRUE))
[1] 2 1 0 1
```

---

Or using `base R`, extract the words into a `list` and then count the the `lengths` of the list i.e. length of each list element

```
lengths(regmatches(vector1, gregexpr("[Ff]rank", vector1)))
[1] 2 1 0 1
```

Comment: Cool - thanks. Is there a solution using only `base` functions?

Comment: @DavidMoore updted the post

Answer (score 2):

Combining `gregexpr` and `regmatches` can be one `base-r` approach

```r
v = c("Frank frank", "Frank", "Fred", "frank")
res = regmatches(v, gregexpr('frank', v, ignore.case = TRUE))
res 
[[1]]
[1] "Frank" "frank"

[[2]]
[1] "Frank"

[[3]]
character(0)

[[4]]
[1] "frank"

lengths(res)

[1] 2 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also collapse the two versions of "Frank" or use a general regex:

```
library(stringr)

str_count(vector1, "[fF]rank")

OR

str_count(vector1, "Frank|frank")

[1] 2 1 0 1
```